# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceReport;

Tags: java, android, gradle, libraries

In the gradle I have added the following dependencies which get synched!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.panagiotis.lalakis"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

 dependencies
      {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
            compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    }
```

No error is marked in the coding process but when I try to build the project I
get the following error

```
 com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
 Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceReport;
```

I understand that there is a conflict but I do not know how to fix it and the articles online are scarce and not enlightening regarding my issue. Could someone suggest me a workaround, please? Thanking you in advance Panos!

Comment: Why are you using `9.4.0` for maps, and `8.4.0` for location?  You should use the same version for both.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same version for both maps and location:

```
  dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
  }
```